# Allow URL with diacritics

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, hyperlinks, unicode

I would like to add my Google+ Profile custom URL to my Stack Exchange profiles. It includes a character with diacritics that is automatically removed.

The URL alone in the Bio doesn't work either.

```
https://plus.google.com/+RubénRivera
```

In the meantime, in the website box I replaced the URL that I want to use with the one with the serial number:

```
https://plus.google.com/113074074636564187023
```

Ideas for implementation

1. Add a special box for Google+ Custom URL in the same way that there is a special box for the Twitter link or Username.
2. Add a "special" markdown for Google+ Custom URL so SE platform has enough context.

Answer (score 14):

You need to provide a *valid* URL; your browser is a lot more tolerant about what characters it accepts, but when I copy the URL from the Chrome location bar I get the *real* URL:

```
https://plus.google.com/+Rub%C3%A9nRivera
```

Note the `%C3` and `%A9` parts; those are UTF-8 bytes encoded using URL percent encoding. The `C3 A9` bytes encode a `é` character.

Using the URL with percent encoding works fine.

Note that Stack Exchange cannot accept 'human readable' URLs because there is no standard encoding to be used. Google+ uses UTF-8, as do a lot of sites, but there is no RFC specification to state what encoding to use here. See [*What every web developer must know about URL encoding*](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding#CommonpitfallsofURLs). A lone URL doesn't provide enough context for Stack Exchange to determine the correct codec to use.

Comment: Using your words, the feature-request is that SE profile be more tolerant so the custom URL links could be "human readable".

Comment: Idea from the answer: where markdown is allowed, the custom URL could be displayed as follow
[https://plus.google.com/+RubénRivera](https://plus.google.com/+Rub%C3%A9nRivera). Use custom URL between [ and ] and encoded / valid URL between ( and ).

Comment: @Rubén: the problem *there* is that not all sites use UTF-8 to encode non-ASCII codepoints.

Comment: A feature request could be a wish, a hope, a desire... Don't you think?

Comment: "A lone URL doesn't provide enough context..." Then add something else to the SE platform so its users could add the required context :)

Comment: UTF-8 is the one true encoding. Any claim of the existence of of other encodings is a lie.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Oh how I wish that were true.